# Apache server slow when high HTTP API call

Tags: php, linux, apache, http, centos

I am running HTTP API which should be called more than 30,000 time per minute simultaneously.
Currently I can call it 1,200 time per minute. If I call 1200 time per minute, all the request are completed and get response immediately.
But if I called 12,000 time per minute simultaneously it take 10 minute to complete all the request. And during that 10 minute, I cannot browse any webpage on the server. It is very slow

I am running CentOS 7

Server  Specification

Intel® Xeon® E5-1650 v3 Hexa-Core Haswell,
RAM 256 GB DDR4 ECC RAM,
Hard Drive2 x 480 GB SSD(Software-RAID 1),
Connection 1 Gbit/s

API- simple php script that echo the time-stamp

```
echo time();
```

I check the top command, there is no load in the server

please help me on it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a congestion problem.
It doesn't matter how quick your script/page handling is, if the next request gets done within the execution time of the previous:

It is going to use resources (cpu, ram, disk, network traffic and connections).
And make everything parallel to it slower.

There are multiple things you could do, but you need to figure out what exactly the problem is for your setup and decide if the measure produces the desired result.

If the core problem is that resources get hogged by parallel processes, you could lower connection limits so more connections go in to wait mode, which keeps more resources available for actually handing out a page instead of congesting everything even more.
Take a look at this:
http://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Tune_apache2_for_more_concurrent_connections

If the server accepts connections quicker then it can handle them, you are going to have a problem which ever you change. It should start dropping connections at some point. If you cram down French baguettes down its throat quicker then it can open its mouth, it is going to suffocate either way.

If the system gets overwhelmed at the network side of things (transfer speed limit, maximum possible of concurent connections for the OS etc etc) then you should consider using a load balancer. Only after the loadbalancer confirms the server has the capacity to actually take care of the page request it will send the user further.
This usually works well when you do any kind of processing which slows down page loading (server side code execution, large volumes of data etc).

Optimise performance 
There are many ways to execute PHP code on a webserver and I assume you use appache. I am no expert, but there are modes like CGI and FastCGI for example. Which can greatly enhance execution speed. And tweaking settings connected to these can also show you what is happening. It could for example be that you use to little number of PHP threats to handle that number of concurrent connections.

Have a look at something like this for example
http://blog.layershift.com/which-php-mode-apache-vs-cgi-vs-fastcgi/

There is no 'best fit for all' solution here. To fix it, you need to figure out what the bottle neck for the server is. And act accordingly.

12000 Calls per minute == 200 calls a second.

You could limit your test case to a multitude of those 200 and increase/decrease it while changing settings. Your goal is to dish that number of requestst out in a shortest amount of time as possible, thus ensuring the congestion never occurs.

That said: consequences.

When you are going to implement changes to optimise the maximum number of page loads you want to achieve you are inadvertently going to introduce other conditions. For example if maximum ram usage by Apache would be the problem, the upping that limit will ensure better performance, but heightens the chance the OS runs out of memory when other processes also want to claim more memory.

Adding a load balancer adds another possible layer of failure and possible slow downs. Yes you prevent congestion, but is it worth the slow down caused by the rerouting?

Upping performance will increase the load on the system, making it possible to accept more concurrent connections. So somewhere along the line a different bottle neck will pop up. High traffic on different processes could always end in said process crashing. Apache is a very well build web server, so it should in theories protect you against said problem, however tweaking settings wrongly could still cause crashes.

So experiment with care and test before you use it live.

Comment: My pleasure. Some other things popped to my mind.

Install htop and have a look at the number of threats being spewed out. That can give you a clue on what is going on.
The mentioned tools here:
atop
iftop
sysstat

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67807/is-there-a-top-like-command-that-shows-the-network-bandwidths-and-file-accesses

Could also help you on your way